# Stable equivalences preserving injective dimension

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A,B$ be two finite dimensional connected algebras and $F$ be a stable equivalence between their stable module categories (module category modulo projectives).

Are there some natural conditions on $F$ so that $F$ preserves the injective dimension of any module (or sends injective modules to injective modules)?

One condition (probably not so natural) is for example that $A$ is selfinjective and $F$ induced by a derived equivalence.